# Запись чисел в лист в виде массива

Tags: java, алгоритм, list, lambda, java-stream

Делаю реализацию игры Mastermind взял за основу алгоритм Кнута.

Столкнулся с проблемой создания Set всех возможных значений.

Значение хранится в массиве для которого я написал класс обертку.

Есть несколько параметров которые влияют на наш массив. Его длинна и количество возможных цифр.

То есть при длине массива 4 и количестве максимальных значений 6 у меня должно получится множество массивов от `[0, 0, 0, 0]` до `[5, 5, 5, 5]`.

Вопрос в том как это можно сделать в цикле с отсечкой по максимальному значению. И как int превратить в массив, что-бы 1 давала массив `[0, 0, 0, 1]`, а не `[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте цикл по числам `0..6^4-1` и представьте счётчик цикла как четырёхразрядное число в шестеричной системе счисления (с помощью операций целочисленного деления и остатка от деления (взятия модуля)). Каждый получившийся разряд соответствует элементу массива.

```
десятичное =>    шестиричное
0          =>    0 0 0 0
1295       =>    5 5 5 5
679        =>    3 0 5 1    (216*3 + 36*0 + 6*5 + 1)
```

Псевдокод:

```
Digits = [0,0,0,0]
for i = 0.. 6*6*6*6-1:
   t = i
   for d = 0..3:
      Digit[d] = t % 6   
      //младший разряд слева - в нулевом индексе
      //для того, чтобы 1 соответствовал массиву [0,0,0,1] - сделать
      //Digit[3 - d] = t % 6   
      t = t / 6    ///целочисленное деление
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял должно получиться так: Вход в первый цикл где считаем до 1295, далее каждое число входим во второй цикл где раскладываем число на массив и записываем его. Раскладываем с помощью операций i%10 i/10 идущих одна за другой пока не кончится число?

Comment: Почти так - только `i%6  i/6`. На всякий случай добавил псевдокод

Answer (score 2):

Просто добавлю реализацию описанного в соседнем ответе механизма с использованием Stream API и встроенными методами перевода значений между системами счисления:

```java
int count = 4, max = 6;

long[][] array = LongStream
    .range(0, Math.round(Math.pow(max, count)))
    .mapToObj(i -> Long.toString(i, max))
    .map(s -> Stream.generate(() -> "0")
        .limit(count - s.length())
        .collect(Collectors.joining()) + s
    )
    .map(s -> s.chars()
        .mapToLong(l -> Long.parseLong(String.valueOf((char) l), max))
        .toArray())
    .toArray(long[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```